# Add multiple titles/text above brackets in facet_wrap ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I would like to add "Pear" and "Apple" as text above the brackets. I cannot find a way to add it as multiple titles , same size and same position.

```
df <- data.frame('fruit'=c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Pear", "Pear"),
                'color'=c("Red", "Red", "Green","Green","Green","Green"), fruitcol=c(rep("AppleRed",2), rep("AppleGreen",2),rep("PearGreen",2)), 'percentage'= c(11,19,34,23,27, 16))

df$fruitcol <- factor(df$fruitcol,  levels = c("AppleRed", "AppleGreen", "PearGreen"),labels = c( "Red", "Green", "Green_"))


the_plot<- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=fruit, y=percentage)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~fruitcol, labeller = label_parsed) + labs(title = "Pear", subtitle="Apple")+ theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(size=18, hjust=0.5, face="italic", color="black"))+
scale_x_discrete("",breaks=c(.5,2.5),labels=c("Low types","High types") ) +
theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length = unit(.85, "cm"), strip.background = element_rect(
     color="black", fill="#FC4E07", size=1.5, linetype="solid"))

library(pBrackets)
the_plot
grid.locator(unit="native") 
top_y <- 40
grid.brackets(55, top_y,   360, top_y, lwd=2, col="black")
grid.brackets(370, top_y,  518, top_y, lwd=2, col="black")
```

[image]

Comment: I am looking forward to the day when people stop using `df` for creating a data frame. otherwise good question

Comment: Working with my data I choose specific names, but for general reproducible examples, I guess it's easier? @tjebo what is your suggestion other ways? :P

Comment: instead of `df`? `df` is a base function. Any other name that is not a base function would do. Like `foo`

Comment: @tjebo I see your point!

Comment: I think `df` is a great name for a data.frame: it is short and descriptive of the type of object. The base function is so rarely used in my own work that I've never had a conflict. Even if a conflict arises I can also refer to `base::df()`.

Comment: lol, I guess it's a matter of opinion. I prefer not to mess with other people's environment :)

Comment: If you're willing to let the bracket idea go, you might find the following useful: https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#nested-facets-1 (disclaimer: I wrote this so I'm not unbiased).

Comment: On second off-topic thought, I was mistaken too and it is not even a base function but it is a stats package function.

Comment: thanks teunbrand, this made my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I favour teunbrand's nested facets option, but here's a hack:

As so very often, you can annotate outside your plot panel.

You'll need to manually chose reasonable theme margins and y-values for the labels.

I am also glad to have learned I was mistaken for quite a long while, thinking `df` would be a base function. I finally can give up on my quest to convince people of stop using this for data frames. Thanks teunbrand

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(grid)
library(pBrackets)

df <- data.frame('fruit'=c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Pear", "Pear"),
                 'color'=c("Red", "Red", "Green","Green","Green","Green"), fruitcol=c(rep("AppleRed",2), rep("AppleGreen",2),rep("PearGreen",2)), 'percentage'= c(11,19,34,23,27, 16))

df$fruitcol <- factor(df$fruitcol,  levels = c("AppleRed", "AppleGreen", "PearGreen"), labels = c( "Red", "Green", "Green_"))

df$title_lab <- rep(c("Pear", "italic('Apple')",""), each = 2)

mypercent <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(fruit, color) %>%
  summarise(sum_perc = sum(percentage))
maxperc <- max(mypercent$sum_perc)
the_plot<-
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x=fruit, y=percentage)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1, y = maxperc + 15, label = title_lab), parse = TRUE)+
  facet_wrap(~ fruitcol, labeller = label_parsed) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, breaks=c(.5,2.5), labels=c("Low types","High types") ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(NA, maxperc)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_rect(
    color="black", fill="#FC4E07", size=1.5, linetype="solid"),
    plot.margin = margin(t = .5, unit = "in")) 


the_plot
grid.locator(unit="native") 
top_y <- 40
grid.brackets(55, top_y,   360, top_y, lwd=2, col="black")
grid.brackets(370, top_y,  518, top_y, lwd=2, col="black")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the `df <- data.frame(...)` darkside Tjebo :D

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.text(x=unit((55+360)/2, 'native'), y=unit(top_y-28, 'native'), label="XXXX", hjust = 0.5, vjust=0)
```

Will add XXXX above your bracket.
But on my test the width of the bracket differs from yours so they don't align correctly.

Its not a particularly slick solution - as a change in the graph width will screw it all up.  for reproducability I'd want 55 and 360 and probably top_y to all be programatically defined not mouse clicks